# Disabling the enforcement of lock screen after idle time via GPO

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I created a GPO for enforcing locked screen after idle time via the Interactive logon: Machine inactivity limit. Tested it on my OU and it worked. So then I disabled it but it STILL locks the workstation. I even deleted the GPO from the OU but it still locks it. What in the world?  Glad I didn't do it company wide! Can someone please help??

Answer (score 2):

Try to create a policy that *disables* whatever settings you have previously enabled in your policy. Removing a policy doesn't reverse the settings.

You can test it locally on one machine using gpedit.msc.

These kind of issues are often referred to as "tattooing" of a policy.

Comment: Well I put the setting back to not configured, wouldn't that be the same?

Comment: @itgirl17 it might not. That's exactly what I meant by the tattooing.

Comment: So is there any way to stop the tattooing effect?  I've deleted the GPO and the pc's still lock.

Comment: NVM, I checked the local group policy on my pc and found that it changes the setting there but for whatever reason it doesn't change it back.